# cannot import name '_pywrap_utils' from 'tensorflow.python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am working on pose estimation using OpenPose. For that I installed `TensorFlow` GPU and installed all the requirements including CUDA development kit.

While running the Python script: 
`C:\Users\abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py`, I encountered the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_pywrap_utils' from
>   'tensorflow.python'
>   (C:\Users\abhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py)

I tried searching for _pywrap_utils file but there was no such file.

Comment: The `_pywrap_utils ` seems to be a function from `tensorflow.python`, check the file for this name. BTW the error is really accusing that the extension is `.python`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install pywrap` and `pip3 install tensorflow` pywrap utils should be included with tensorflow. If it is not found, that means TF was not installed correctly.